# how to get database table name for each field in datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server

I know how to get the name of a field within a `DataTable`:

```
col.ColumnName
```

How do I get the database Table name (not the `DataTable.TableName`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database table name is not returned in the `DataTable`. You should know the table name from the select statement (if a proc, look at the proc code) you used to populate the `DataTable`

Comment: In this case, I'm using a DB view as my select statement. So in my case, there are around 15 DB tables in the `DataTable` and some overlapping fields, so I can't know where they come from. But it looks like it's not possible at all. At least I know and can try a different method then.

Comment: Yes, that's not possible. you can get the info from the View definition if you have access to it. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

`DataTable` is a table in memory. It does not keep track of from which database table it got filled.

Suppose I am using this select statement to fill a DataTable

```
select * from foo,bar where foo.id = bar.id
```

Now tell me what should be DataTable name.

What you can do is when filling datatable, give it a table name like this

```
mydatatable = new DataTable("SomeTableName");
```